# Automatic linebreak in table cell with p doesn't work

Tags: tables

I am using the following code.
In the p{6cm} column there comes no automatic line break in the text of the cell. Instead of this, the too long text overwrites the right cell. What do i wrong?

```
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}lrc}
\rowcolor{heading}\bf{Projektphase} & \bf{Beteiligter Mitarbeiter} & \bf{Dauer} & \bf{Zeitraum} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Planung und Entwurf} & Ordnas & 5 \mbox{h} & \multirow{2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
& Christoph Frohnhöfer & 2 \mbox{h} & \\
\rowcolor{odd}& Sandro Roch & 20 \mbox{h} & \\
\rowcolor{odd}\multirow{-2}{*}{Implementieren der Datenermittlung und -aufbereitung} & Muria & 2 \mbox{h} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Zeitraum}\\
\multirow{2}{*}{Implementieren der Benutzeroberfläche} & Franz & 35 \mbox{h} & \multirow{2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
& Maria & 3 \mbox{h} & \\
\rowcolor{odd}Entwicklertest & Markus & 2 \mbox{h} & Zeitraum \\
Qualitätssicherung & QS-Mitarbeiter & 1 \mbox{h} & Zeitraum \\
\rowcolor{odd}& Peter & 1 \mbox{h} & \\
\rowcolor{odd}\multirow{-2}{*}{Abnahme durch Projektverantwortlichen} & Moritz & 1 \mbox{h} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
Projektdokumentation & Fritz & 7 \mbox{h} & Zeitraum \\
\hline
\hline
\rowcolor{heading}\bf{Summe} & & \bf{79 \mbox{h}} &
\end{tabular}
```

Thank you for answering!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\bf` is deprecated for 20 years now, please use `\textbf{...}`

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Did `\bf` ever take an argument even before it was deprecated? (It was before I even knew about LaTeX so I've never used it.)

Comment: @cfr: No, not as far as I know

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe, `\multirow` does not use `p{...}`, although `{*}` has been specified

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought that also but, like you, I am not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `*` option the argument to `multirow` is put in an ordinary (h)box, so does not get line breaks.  If you specify a concrete width then line breaks are allowed.  As you are already using a `p` column with a given a width, you can use the same width for your `multirow`s:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{p{6cm}lrc}
    \rowcolor{red}\textbf{Projektphase} & \textbf{Beteiligter Mit.} & \textbf{Dauer} & \textbf{Zeitraum} \\
    \multirow{2}{6cm}{Planung und Entwurf} & Ordnas & 5 \mbox{h} & \multirow{2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
    & Christoph Frohnhöfer & 2 \mbox{h} & \\
    \rowcolor{green}& Sandro Roch & 20 \mbox{h} & \\
    \rowcolor{green}\multirow{-2}{6cm}{Implementieren der Datenermittlung und -aufbereitung} & Muria & 2 \mbox{h} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Zeitraum}\\
    \multirow{2}{6cm}{Implementieren der Benutzeroberfläche} & Franz & 35 \mbox{h} & \multirow{2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
    & Maria & 3 \mbox{h} & \\
    \rowcolor{green}Entwicklertest & Markus & 2 \mbox{h} & Zeitraum \\
    Qualitätssicherung & QS-Mitarbeiter & 1 \mbox{h} & Zeitraum \\
    \rowcolor{green}& Peter & 1 \mbox{h} & \\
    \rowcolor{green}\multirow{-2}{6cm}{Abnahme durch Projektverantwortlichen} & Moritz & 1 \mbox{h} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
    Projektdokumentation & Fritz & 7 \mbox{h} & Zeitraum \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \rowcolor{red}\textbf{Summe} & & \textbf{79 \mbox{h}} &
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your \multirow as a `\parbox{6cm}` by specifying its width. I added some suggestions to improve your table, with the `makecell` and `siunitx` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}%[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\colorlet{heading}{Thistle2!50}
\colorlet{odd}{LightSteelBlue2}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}
\renewcommand\cellset{\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}lS[table-format = 2.0] c}
\rowcolor{heading}\thead{\raggedleft Projektphase} & \thead{Beteiligter Mitarbeiter} & {\makecell{Dauer\\ \mdseries (h)}} & \thead{Zeitraum} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Planung und Entwurf} & Ordnas & 5 & \multirow{2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
& Christoph Frohnhöfer & 2 & \\
\rowcolor{odd}& Sandro Roch & 20 & \\
\rowcolor{odd}\multirow{-2}{6cm}{Implementieren der Datenermittlung und -aufbereitung} & Muria & 2 & \multirow{-2}{*}{Zeitraum}\\
\multirow{2}{*}{Implementieren der Benutzeroberfläche} & Franz & 35 & \multirow{2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
& Maria & 3 & \\
\rowcolor{odd}Entwicklertest & Markus & 2 & Zeitraum \\
Qualitätssicherung & QS-Mitarbeiter & 1 & Zeitraum \\
\rowcolor{odd}& Peter & 1 & \\
\rowcolor{odd}\multirow{-2}{*}{Abnahme durch Projektverantwortlichen} & Moritz & 1 & \multirow{-2}{*}{Zeitraum} \\
Projektdokumentation & Fritz & 7 & Zeitraum \\
\hline
\hline
\rowcolor{heading}\thead{Summe} & & \bfseries 79 &    
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image]